# How to read json data from HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, json, rest, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am using HttpURLConnection from application1 to get json data from applicaton2. 'applicaton2' sets json data in Rest response object. How can i read that json data after getting response in application1.

Sample code:

Application1:

```
url = "url to application2";
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
```

Application2":

```
List<ModelA> lListModelAs = Entities data;
GenericEntity<List<ModelA>> lEntities = new GenericEntity<List<ModelA>>(lListModelAs) {};
lResponse = Response.ok(lEntities ).build();
```

I need to read above json data from urlConnection from response.

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After setting up your HttpURLConnection.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

  StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
  String line;

    JsonObject obj = new JsonParser().parse(reader).getAsJsonObject();


         boolean status = contentObj.get("status").getAsBoolean();
         String Message = contentObj.get("msg").getAsString();
         String Regno = contentObj.get("regno").getAsString();
        String User_Id = contentObj.get("userid").getAsString();
        String SessionCode = contentObj.get("sesscode").getAsString();
```

You can download the gson jar here [enter link description here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/jar)

Answer (score 1):

Use dedicated library for json serialization/deserialization, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for example. It will allow you to read json content directly from `InputStream` into POJOs that maps the response. It will be something like that:

```
MyRestResponse response=objectMapper.readValue(urlConnection.getInput(),MyRestResponse.class);
```

Looking good isnt it??

Here you have Jackson project GitHub page with usage examples.
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: Thanks for the answer.This will read into single object, but i want it as list, how to do that?

Comment: You can have list of objects etc. whatever you would like. Eg insteed `MyRestResponse response` you can have `List<SomeJSONMappedObjectPOJO> response`

Answer (score 1):

You can use gson library 
https://github.com/google/gson for parsing your data

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourClass objOfYourClass = gson.fromJson(urlConnection.getInputStream(), YourClass.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.This will read into single object, but i want it as list, how to do that?

Comment: one way is YourClass[].class